# How to get icon image

Tags: c#, image, listview, window

I want to make same Window File explorer.

but I don't know how to get file default Icon image.

If I can get file default image(Icon), I would like to add to the listview.

my code is as below

```
private void AddFiles(string strPath)
{
       lv_local.BeginUpdate();
       lv_local.Items.Clear();
       iFiles = 0;
          try
           {
           DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(strPath + "\\");
           FileInfo[] theFiles = di.GetFiles();
           foreach (FileInfo theFile in theFiles)
           {
            iFiles++;
            ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(theFile.Name);
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(String.Format("{0:N0}", theFile.Length) + "KB");
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(theFile.Extension);
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(theFile.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString());
            lvItem.ImageIndex = 4;
            // I want to put an image that was read default image
            lv_local.Items.Add(lvItem);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Exc) 
            {  
            }

            lv_local.EndUpdate();
 }
```

Comment: `System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create ImageList and add icons**

```
var imageList = new ImageList();

imageList.Images.Add("IconKey", icon);
```

**Assign the ImageList to ListView**

```
listView.LargeImageList = imageList;
```

**Assign icon for the list view item**

```
listViewItem.ImageKey = "itemImageKey";
```

or `listViewItem.ImageIndex = 1;`